# Power BI Dataset can not find Firebird database

Tags: powerbi, odbc, firebird, powerbi-datasource, firebird-3.0

After a Firebird 3.0 update, our PowerBI Dataset can't find the Firebird database, although the ODBC Setup works just fine.

[image: Power BI Service - Error Message]

[image: Firebird ODBC Setup]

But the most bizarre part, I can create a new Dataflow-set with the exact same data source (same Gateway to ODBC Source) and it works!
I've created a whole new Workspace and uploaded the Dataset/Report into it, the same error occurs.

Some Info:

1. We've recently updated our Firebird database from 2.5 to 3.0
2. Our connection worked just fine with 2.5

The ODBC-Source connects to a raw Firebird (main.FDP) database.

A direct connection to the live-Data is not possible, the ODBC-Setup throws an error (File database not found), so I copied the main.FDP into a different folder, that way the ODBC setup connects successfully.

On Power BI Desktop via Power Query Editor, I can see the actual live data, but if I "Close & Apply", the same error occurs (File Database not found) on the refreshing window.

Comment: Have you configured a 32-bit or 64-bit DSN? Is Power BI a 64-bit or 32-bit application. Have you installed the 32-bit and 64-bit fbclient.dll?

Comment: Make sure you specify the Firebird server host name (e.g. `localhost:C:\ProgramData\....`) in your connection URL and not just the file name. Firebird 3.0 defaults to using embedded connection mode if you only specify a filename (where Firebird 2.5 would use "local" connection mode using XNET), which might be what trips you up here (e.g. if Power BI doesn't have sufficient read/write access to the database file or lock files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Rotteveel, thanks for the Solution.

The Solution was the pathing, i added "localhost:[...]" as prefix and it works.